# ScalaTest throwing a ClassNotFoundException

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'm running the following empty test in Scala IDE and getting an error.

```
import org.scalatest._

class TheTest extends FlatSpec {
  "blaah" should "be blaah" in {

  }
}
```

> *** RUN ABORTED ***   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TheTest   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$35.apply(Runner.scala:2438)   at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$35.apply(Runner.scala:2436)   at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filterImpl$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:259)
>   at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)   at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:258)
>   at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:270)
>   at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104) 
>   ...

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` usually means that compilation failed. Check for any compile errors.

Comment: can you post your build.sbt and plugins.sbt file?

Comment: try `sbt clean` -> `sbt update` -> `sbt compile`